# function works but don't alert and reload

Tags: javascript

I wrote a small form to log-in into my website :

```
<form id="log_form" onsubmit='return loginjs()' method="post">
<input type='text' placeholder="login" size='30' name='login' class='test'/>
<input type='password' placeholder="password" name='password' size='30'/>
<input type='submit' value='Connect' id='signin' />
</form>
```

and I wrote this Javascript function to send the form's data to a php page which going to check if everything is ok and make the session up.

```
function loginjs() {
  'use strict';
  var form = document.getElementById('log_form');
  var btn = document.getElementById('signin');
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if(request.status === 200) {
        if (request.responseText != 'ok')
            alert(request.responseText);
      }      
    }
  }
  var post = "login=" + form.login.value + "&password=" + form.password.value;
  request.open('POST', 'functions/func_login.php');
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  request.send(post);
  location.reload();
};
```

My function is perfectly called each time I press ENTER or click on Submit, but sometimes the alert doesn't show up and the location.reload(); aren't called. 
I don't have any error in my console... and if I manually reload the page, i'm logged so my ajax was sent.

I'm looking for 2 days to find the bug, and doesn't succeed to find. Could someone help me?

I can't use jQuery or another library I've to use JS Vanilla :)

Thank you

Comment: You don't appear to be cancelling the default form submission.

Comment: What's on `func_login.php`. There might be the error.

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/raw/QETvM9xf)

Here is my func_login.php

Comment: Your alert isn't invoked if everything is ok

Comment: Yes it supposed to be invocked if something wrong, and sometimes when something is wrong, it doesn't alert.
And sometimes when everything is ok, it doesn't reload though.
But if I reload manually I'm well logged ! So I don't think it's the php code

Comment: Do you want to see those messages from php on your page?

Comment: That'll unlikely fix the issue but 'return loginjs()' looks strange to me.. Why not 'loginjs()'?

Comment: my func get the answer from my php page and it works 9 times on 10 ...
just sometimes it looks like to just ignore the alert() or the reload.

Comment: you are right my return is useless I remove it!

Comment: How do you know that not everything is good but alert isn't invoked?

Comment: @Dzmtrs I know that my function well sent the ajax to php because if I reload manually the page with cmd+r , I'm logged

Comment: your `loginjs` should return false otherwise it'll always submit.

Comment: Have you thought that if your alert isn't invoked then maybe the request is ok?

Comment: Yes but if the request is ok, @Dzmtrs , it should at least reload the page...

Comment: Maybe the request is ok but the body of the message isn't ok

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the `location.reload();` code in the success block of the ajax, i.e. reload the page after the ajax response is received (if no error is received).

Comment: I removed it.
It also reload the page without this line...
But still have the problem.